# How to repeate a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, repeat

I've tried several ways to do this but I can't, I need to repeat to unlimited the function `nombreintroducido` until there's a value that's not `''`, and this script only works once, it repeats it only once.

```js
var nombrepersonaje = function(name) {
  return nombre = prompt("Como quieres que se llame tu personaje");
  nombreintroducido();
}

nombrepersonaje();

var nombreintroducido = function (introducido){
  if (nombre === '') {
    confirm('Tu nombre de personaje ha de tener mas de 3 caracteres');
    nombrepersonaje();
  } else {
    confirm('Tu nombre de personaje es' + ' ' + nombre)
  }
};

nombreintroducido();
```

Comment: Shouldn't `nombrepersonaje()` be in else as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code after a `return` statement does not run. I think you want something like

```js
var nombrepersonaje = function() {
  var nombre = prompt("Como quieres que se llame tu personaje");
  nombreintroducido(nombre);
};
var nombreintroducido = function(nombre){
  if (nombre === '') {
    confirm('Tu nombre de personaje ha de tener mas de 3 caracteres');
    nombrepersonaje();
  } else {
    confirm('Tu nombre de personaje es' + ' ' + nombre)
  }
};
nombrepersonaje();
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the `while` loop.

```
var nombreintroducido = function (introducido) {
    while (nombre === '') {
        setTimeout(prompt('Tu nombre de personaje ha de tener mas de 3 caracteres'), 1000);
        nombrepersonaje();
    }
};
```

Comment: It should be `prompt` and not `confirm`

Comment: I would add a delay in there, else most browsers will start complaining :)